# Why is the end time for the moderator voting not posted on the vote page?

Tags: discussion, voting, moderators

Why is the end time for the moderator voting not posted on the [vote page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/vote-moderator)?

Comment: Super Monkey Ba------I mean, Super Mega Upvote!!!

Comment: Starts with why. Is not what is the term of voting. Is not why one week. Is not what color to paint a bus.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the time wasn't posted on the election thread for a while, I'm guessing they are using the same philosophy. *6-8 weeks (or sooner)*

Edit: I guess the [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/02/stack-overflow-2010-moderator-election-begins/) says one week..... I feel sad now...

Comment: The blog post (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/02/stack-overflow-2010-moderator-election-begins/) says one week.

Comment: I feel sad too... Only one week? That's barely enough time to paint the bus, much less get yard signs put out!

Comment: You said "funny quote". But all you did was put in lines from *Family Guy*.

Comment: Well, lets see ... I'm going to send that one back to our Joke Department, and get back to you in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: +1, *Family Guy.* -1, editing out *Family Guy.* Net: Sorry bud, but 0.